# Codeigniter user access level

Tags: php, codeigniter

Model:

```
Class User extends CI_Controller
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('id', 'username', 'password', 'access');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //Field validation failed.&nbsp; User redirected to login page
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }

        else
        {
            //Go to private area
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
        }

    }

    function check_database($password)
    {
        //Field validation succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database
        $username = $this->input->post('username');

        //query the database
        $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

        if($result)
        {
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $sess_array = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'username' => @$row->username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to deal with access? In the database is int number, you need to make a selection from the base, to get the numbers from the table and access to work with him. How to implement it?

Comment: Sorry but didn't understood what you need so,please elaborate clearly to get quicker help

Comment: Need to get the value of the table access to work with him. For example in the table is meant for using with access 4 - then it's the admin and the template for example can do this: if ($this->access(4)) {echo "You admin"}. You need something like

Comment: Still didn't got you clearly but looks like you need to check access level of logged in user ? Am i right ?

Comment: I want to get the access level for that user in the future to use as I told you, for example through if () {}

Comment: Ok..so you have shown in your code that you are selecting 'access' field.Use that to know the access level.What problem you have in that ?

Comment: how to use and implement in my code?

Comment: As i see from your query that you have access level so you can use that to find which level of user is logged in.I guess what implementation you want to do and what you done to achieve it will be important.

For example : `$result->access == 1 ? 'admin' : 'not admin'`

Comment: whether it is possible to describe in a separate class check on the level of access that would continue to use it through if for example: if(access=Admin) { echo "<a href="admin.php">adminpanel</a>

Comment: Whatever you want to use through out your project store it in sessions and use it where ever required.
For codeigniter session check this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html